# What does top, left, right and bottom mean in Android Rect object

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-shape

I have an Android project where I should make Apples fall. The apples are painted in a Rect. So I created a function that change the Rect position and repaint. Here's my function :

```
private void updateApplesPosition() {
    for(Rect rect:fallingDownFruitsList)
        rect.set(rect.left, rect.top +10, rect.right, rect.bottom +10);
}
```

I have a problem : the Apples don't fall but go from right to left. To make the apples fall I changed the code by this :

```
private void updateApplesPosition() {
    for(Rect rect:fallingDownFruitsList)
        rect.set(rect.left+10, rect.top, rect.right+10, rect.bottom);
}
```

Comment: use Rect.offset(dx, dy)

Comment: they dont go by themselves, you draw them and the bug is there

Comment: `Rect` works just fine, therefore the problem is how you draw them.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

**This image will explain you in detail:**

[image]

> **left**  The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle
>
> **top**   The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle
>
> **right** The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle
>
> **bottom**    The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot @Log, I've been breaking my head for two days to understand what left, right and bottom meant. It's unfortunate Android developers documentation is so unexplanatory about this class.

Comment: @LOG_TAG : The values are in pixels or integers?

Comment: rect.top will gives the pixel value or dp value ?

Comment: The values are in pixels

Comment: Note: When you print a `Rect` object to the Logcat console, it will show something like `"Rect(790, 960 - 831, 1025)"`. These numbers are pixel coordinates that mean: `Rect(left, top - right, bottom)`. See info here: [android.graphics.Rect.java -> toString()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-14.0.0_r11/graphics/java/android/graphics/Rect.java#152)

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](http://bit.ly/OK8b29)

**Parameters**

> **left**  The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle
>
> **top**   The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle
>
> **right** The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle
>
> **bottom**    The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle

Comment: I have read the docs but why when I do rect.top +10 it goes to left and not going down

Comment: @user230137 _setBounds(x-width/2, y-height/2, x+width/2, y+height/2)_    where  _int width = getWidth()/10;int height = getHeight()/10;_

Comment: @adneal : are these values in pixels?

Comment: @Aniruddha yes the values are in pixels

Answer (score 1):

Adding a crucial information.

The documentation says:

> Note that the right and bottom coordinates are exclusive.

So if your rectangle is a **single** pixel at position 10,10

left = 10 : The X coordinate of the left side of the rectangle

top = 10 : The Y coordinate of the top of the rectangle = 10

right = 11 : The X coordinate of the right side of the rectangle **plus one**

bottom = 11 : The Y coordinate of the bottom of the rectangle **plus one**

> Note that the right and bottom coordinates are exclusive.

The methods getWidth is declared as such

> public final int width() { return right - left; }

Here it will return 11 - 10 = 1, as expected.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect